# Trying to print a user input phrase into a V shape

Tags: java

I did quiet a bit of searching and have found tons of ways to output stars and other shapes into countless patterns but I have not found anything as to how to do this with a user generated phrase.

So to clarify my question I want to be able to take a user input, we could call it String userInput, and make it print userInput in a "V" shape.

I am thinking I need to create a loop. But I am confused as to exactly how to make it print the individual characters in their correct places. Below is what I have so far and the output I am currently getting.

```
    public class VShape {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a phrase: ");

    int length = userInput.length();

    System.out.println("Phrase: "+ userInput);


    if ((length%2)==0)
    {
        System.out.println("The length of the phrase is: EVEN");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The length of the phrase is: ODD");
    }

    for (int i =0; i<length; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }

}


run:
Phrase: 123456
The length of the phrase is: EVEN
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

- This was marked as a duplicate to a question about a diamond pattern. The question on how to print a diamond pattern is printing spaces and *. What I am trying to figure out is how to take a phrase. Such as "The house is blue" and have it print in a "V" shape. I am having the most trouble trying to figure out what to tell my loop to actually do once it meets all its conditions. For example, how would I tell it to print the first char "T" then the next char "H" in their correct places?

maybe that clarifies a little better.

Comment: The question on how to print a diamond pattern is printing spaces and *. What I am trying to figure out is how to take a phrase. Such as "The house is blue" and have it print in a "V" shape. I am having the most trouble trying to figure out what to tell my loop to actually do once it meets all its conditions. For example, how would I tell it to print the first char "T" then the next char "H" in their correct places?

Comment: While one can learn from the question about a diamond pattern, I agree that it is not duplicate.

Comment: Try this :http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/807643

Comment: You my friend are genius. Now I just have to decipher what it all means so I can understand it lol. Not your fault though, I am still very much new to this and like I mentioned below; just started learning arrays.

Comment: If something is not clear feel free to post another question (if you do please  post here a link to it)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
The question was about Java. My answer was in C#. Here is the Java version:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String input = "1234567";
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

    String [] lines = new String[input.length() / 2 + 1];
    int i, k;

    for(i = 0; i<input.length() /2 ;i++) {

        // Take the i-th char from the beginning
        char begChar = inputArray[i];
        char endChar = inputArray[input.length() - i - 1];

        // calculate numbers of spaces:
        int spacesBefore = i;
        int spacesAfter = i;
        int spacesInBetween = input.length() - 2 - 2*i;

        // Create the string
        String line = "";
        for(k = 0; k < spacesBefore; k++) { line += " "; }
        line += begChar;
        for(k = 0; k < spacesInBetween; k++) { line += " "; }
        line += endChar;

        lines[i] = line;
    }

    // In the end, if the length is odd, create the last line for the last char
    if(input.length() % 2 != 0) {
        String lastLine = "";
        for (k= 0;k<input.length() /2; k++) {
            lastLine+=" ";
        }
        lastLine += inputArray[input.length() /2];
        lines[input.length() / 2] = lastLine;
    }

    // output
    for(i=0;i<lines.length && lines[i] != null; i++) {
        System.out.println(lines[i]);
    }

 }
```

The old answer in C# is below:

```
public static void VOutput(string input)
{
    var inputArray = input.ToCharArray();

    string [] lines = new string[input.Length / 2 + 1];

    for(var i = 0; i<input.Length /2 ;i++) {

        // Take the i-th char from the beginning
        var begChar = inputArray[i];
        var endChar = inputArray[input.Length - i - 1];

        // calculate numbers of spaces:
        var spacesBefore = i;
        var spacesAfter = i;
        var spacesInBetween = input.Length - 2 - 2*i;

        // Create the string
        string line = String.Empty;
        for(var k = 0; k < spacesBefore; k++) { line += " "; }
        line += begChar;
        for(var k = 0; k < spacesInBetween; k++) { line += " "; }
        line += endChar;

        lines[i] = line;
    }

    // In the end, if the length is odd, create the last line for the last char
    if(input.Length % 2 != 0) {
        var lastLine = String.Empty;
        for (var k= 0;k<input.Length/2; k++) {
            lastLine+=" ";
        }
        lastLine += inputArray[input.Length /2];
        lines[input.Length / 2] = lastLine;
    }

    // output
    foreach(var line in lines) {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Personal comment: While I do agree that the code was not in the language that was requested, it took literally 6 minutes to switch it to Java, including complex changes like changing "ToCharArray()" to "toCharArray()" and similar. I think some of you could have made the attempt instead of giving negative points. Thanks.

Comment: this is not even [tag:java] code!

Comment: I tried copying and pasting this into my IDE and wasn't able to figure it out. I am just beginning to learn arrays. So that could be part of the problem.

Comment: It is not java code

Comment: I apologize everyone, this is C# code - it was 5am and I just missed that the question was Java based. Will edit now.

Comment: Yes, this looks more like Java (-: